# Trying to get a Count value from a MVC action via ajax jQuery call, need to check code

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to get a count value from a MVC action after a prior MVC action has done some processing which is also ajax. The prior action is downloading a file.

So thoughts on JQuery is :

```
$(function () {
    $('#DownloadDoc').click(function () {

        $... // Call first process, works fine.
        $.ajax({
            url: "@(Url.Action("GetCount", "Controller"}, null))",
            success: function (intCount) {
                $("#divCount").html(intCount);
            }
        });            
        return true;
    });
});
```

I suspect the Action would look something like, bit fuzzy on this, so is incorrect syntax:

```
        public ActionResult GetCount()
        {
          int intCount = 1;
          Return intCount;
        }
```

I would really appreciate some clarification on the Action and JQuery syntax please.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Check your ajax syntax.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I was hoping for some guidance as I am a novice at JQuery and JQuery/MVC interaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this,

```
$(function () {
    $('#DownloadDoc').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetCount", "Controller")',
            success: function (intCount) {
                $("#divCount").html(intCount);
            }
        });            
    });
});
```

**Controller**

```
public JsonResult GetCount()
{
 int intCount = 1;
 return Json(intCount,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: @SamJolly WC. If any concern let me know.